# Creating a cell array of workspace variables without manually writing them all out. MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have 20 column vectors in the workspace and I'd like them all to be contained within a cell array. They're all labelled data1, data2, data3,...data20.

Is there a faster way to do this than:

```
cell = {data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, ...}
```

all the way up to data20?

Comment: You should really think about your variable names. Using `cell` as a variable name you shadow the built-in function and keeping indices in the variable names causes all the trouble here. You should use a cell instead and never create such variable names.

Comment: If it's really important to have variables named like that, then I would stick them into a structure as fields: `myStruct.data1 = ...`. This way at least you can make use of dynamic field references like this: `myStruct.('data1')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the fastest way, but you could do it as follows:

1. Saving the desired variables in a temporary file
2. Loading that file to get all those variables in a struct array
3. Converting that struct array to a cell array

That is,

```
save temp_file -regexp data\d+    %// step 1
allData = load('temp_file.mat');  %// step 2
allData = struct2cell(allData);   %// step 3
```

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in my comment, such variable names are a bad idea. If you really have to use them and there is no other possibility, use this code to get a cell array:

```
C=cell(1,3)
for ix=1:numel(C),C{ix}=eval(sprintf('data%d',ix));end
```

I recommend not to use eval, details here: [Why avoid the eval functions and alternatives to it.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html)

Comment: I concur in the recommendation to avoid those separate variables

Comment: thanks for the help. a bit confused though: how else should I have initially saved the data if not numerically labelled? each number corresponds to a different image I performed analysis on

Comment: Use a cell array directly: something like `for n = 1:20, load yourImage; data{n} = yourImage; end`